# UITextfield constraints in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with `UITableViewCells` that contain a `UITextfield`, but when I test it on other devices, it doesn't have any constraint. I want it to stick to the right of the `UITableViewCell`, how do I add this programmatically?

```
nameField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:nameField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
            [nameField addConstraint:constraint2];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:nameField];
```

Comment: That doesn't work... I use AutoLayout

Comment: 1) to expect from programmatic constraints kind of work you should at least try to add them. It doesnt obvious from your code how did you do that.
2)  if on "other" devices you do not have any constraints, on which devices you do?

Comment: I haven't added any constraints programmatically, as I don't know how I would go on with doing that with my configuration here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:nameField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0]
[textField addConstraint:constraint];
```

Disclaimer: Did this all in this text editor for the answer, so it may not be syntactically correct, but this is the general idea. If you need any help, just let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the answe Bill, although that code seems to crash when you load the view.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Like I said, I may have mistyped something or gotten something wrong since I never plugged into a debugger -- but this general idea (as long as it is all syntactically correct) should do it programmatically, this is how I add 99% of my constraints.

Answer (score 0):

**I hope it's help you.**
// you can set UITextField alignment on right side

```
UITextField *nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 8, 185, 30)];
nameField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

[nameField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:15]];

[nameField setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[nameField setDelegate:self];
[nameField setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

cell.textLabel.text = @"Server Name";
            [nameField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            nameField.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;  // you can set right alignment
            nameField.text = [serverInfo valueForKey:@"name"];
            [textFields addObject:nameField];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:nameField];
```

Comment: This will align the text inside the control on the right. The OP wants the whole view to stick to the right side of the cell.

Comment: author asked about UITextField's alignment within the cell, but not about text within UITextField

Comment: @slxl i can help him i have to solve his problem so why are you decrease my answer.

Comment: No its true, I am not seeking to align the TEXT, I want the whole textfield to stick to the right side of the view.

Comment: @MadsOdgaard  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-creating-a-custom-text-input-view--mobile-15661

Comment: @SandyPatel thats amazing that you have to solve his problem, but again, Mads asked about autolayout and constraints, but you are posting a link which tells about autoresizing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code (replacing my field with yours). I use it to center my text view but I changed the horizontal constraint so it right-justifies it instead.

```
     cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourCustomCell"];
     [[cell.contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
     UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
     myLabel.text = @"Detail";
     //Create your text view here
     [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:nameField];
     myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
     nameField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
     NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
     NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myLabel, nameField);
     NSString *verForName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|[nameField]|"];
     NSString *verForLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|[myLabel]|"];
     NSString *horForView = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|[myLabel]->=1-[nameField]-15-|"];
     [result addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:verForLabel options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
     [result addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:verForName options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
     [result addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:horForView options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];

     [cell.contentView addConstraints:result];      }
```

Comment: The code crashes with this: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview

Comment: Could you post your code? That message indicates you did not add your field to the cell.contentview.

Comment: I've posted the code I am currenty using in my post

Comment: I edited my code snippet. Try it again replacing the comment with  your text view creation and change your cell type to Custom.

Comment: Hi, this works, although the textfield is all the way to the right, I would like a bit of margin to the edge of the screen, just like the detailtextlabel has.

Comment: I changed my snippet. See horForView (added 15 margin) and play with it until you like the spacing. If this worked please mark it as the answer.

Comment: Mads if this worked for you please up vote it or mark it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `nameField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` if you are doing autolayout.

And after that you just have to create the constrint:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:nameField 
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight 
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                     toItem:cell attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight 
                                                     multiplier:1.0 constant:0]
[namefield addConstraint:constraint];
```

and the constraints for the dimensions - height and width.

Comment: Hi, this also crashes with this: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'